# how to push ViewController from xib tableview Cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tableView within collectionView and i created using xib. I want to pushViewController when item is selected .I tried pushing the view controller in itemForRowAt method but it's not possible

```
class SecondTableView: UITableViewCell , UIcollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource {


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//        let vc = DataTableViewController()
//        vc.delegate = self
//        vc.pushNav()

        let memeVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MemeViewController") as! MemeViewController
        memeVC.imagePassed = image
        navigationController?.pushViewController(memeVC, animated: true)
          print("item tapped\(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

errors 
    Use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard'; did you mean 'UIStoryboard'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522957/call-storyboard-scene-programmatically-without-needing-segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add segue as mentioned in the image and select *show***

[image]

**Set segue identifier in your storyboard as mentioned in the image**

[image]

**Add below Protocol:**

```
protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate: class {
    func userDidTap()
}
```

**Add below property in your table view class where the collection view delegate returns.**

```
weak var delegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate?
```

**Update delegate method**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
              delegate.userDidTap()
              print("item tapped\(indexPath)")
        }
    }
```

**confirm CollectionViewCellDelegate delegate to your first view controller & add this method:**

```
func userDidTap() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMemeViewController", sender: nil)
}
```

**Add prepare for segue in your first VC.**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showMemeViewController" {
            let memeVC: MemeViewController = segue.destination as! MemeViewController
            memeVC.imagePassed = image
        }
    }
```

**Please try this let me know if you faced any other issue. Thanks.**

Comment: @user3871074, I have updated the answer please check,

Comment: I can't perform the segue in UiTableViewCell class.I am looking for a way to communicate (cell -> ViewController)the class that holds tableviewCell

Comment: you need to add a delegate protocol.  I have updated the answer try now.

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value .When i tap on cell

Comment: delegate.dataPassed(img[indexPath.row]) passing an image

Comment: Glad to help you friend :) @user3871074

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access storyboard property in a tableview cell, which isn't there in the first place, it's a UIViewController property not a UITableViewCell property, hence the error, you'll have to delegate your selection to the viewController then let the controller do the segue normally.

You can start doing that via delegates as I mentioned above, for example if you're passing image to the controller you wanna segue to:

```
protocol ImageTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    // pass the the image or any variable you want in the func params
    func userDidTap(_ image: UIImage)
}
```

then you'd add it to the cell and confirm the controller to it

```
class SecondTableView {
  weak var delegate: ImageTableViewCellDelegate?
}
```

In your controller:

```
extension MyViewController: ImageTableViewCellDelegate {
    func userDidTap(_ image: UIImage){
        let memeVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MemeViewController") as! MemeViewController
        memeVC.imagePassed = image
        navigationController?.pushViewController(memeVC, animated: true)
          print("item tapped\(indexPath)")
     }

}
```

this should work, let me know if you had any further problems

Comment: Can you explain how should i do that

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: When are you exactly getting this?

Comment: when i click on the cell

Comment: Are you calling delegate?.userdidtap there?

Comment: let controler = DataTableViewController()
        controler.dataPassed(img[indexPath.row])

Comment: That’s totally wrong, you’re creating a new instance here, please revise using delegates between views and viewcontroller to understand this more, you’re totally not understanding it

Comment: what to do then .where should i call this function?